# $\frac{dy}{dx}$ of an n-ellipse

Tags: calculus, derivatives, circles, conic-sections, implicit-differentiation

An [n-ellipse](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/N-ellipse) is a generalization of a circle with $n$ foci. It can be written as $\sum\sqrt{(x-a)^2 + (y-b)^2} = R$. I am curious as to the derivative $\frac{dy}{dx}$ of this relation.

Using implicit differentiation and differentiating the left side term by term, I found the solution to be $\sum[(x-a)+(y-b)\frac{dy}{dx}] = 0$, or $    \frac{dy}{dx} = -\frac{\sum(x-a)}{\sum(y-b)}$. This is a very simple variation on $\frac{dy}{dx}$ of a circle.

However, the behavior of $\frac{dy}{dx}$ is different in an n-ellipse than a circle, leading me to believe my differentiation is incorrect. [In a circle, $\frac{dy}{dx}$ is independent of radius](https://www.desmos.com/calculator/zcrp2irpnc). However, [in a 3-ellipse, changing the "radius" on the RHS changes the derivative](https://www.desmos.com/calculator/gvwgkcfxrf). What's wrong with my derivation or interpretation?

Comment: How can $\frac{dy}{dx}$ for a circle be independent of $R$? For a circle centered at the origin, at $x=x_0$ we clearly have $\frac{dy}{dx}\to \infty$ as $R$ gets closer to $x_0$ (from above). That's not independence.

Comment: Then can you address how R doesn’t appear in the derivative of either after using implicit differentiation?

Comment: It _does_ appear. It's just hidden inside $y$. (Calculate the derivative for a concrete value of $x$ and $R$, and you'll see what I mean.)

Comment: Can you explain how your Desmos diagram shows that $\frac{dy}{dx}$ is independent of radius?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you are assuming that

$\sum_{i=1}^n\sqrt{(x-a_i)^2 + (y-b_i)^2} = R \space \Rightarrow \space \sum_{i=1}^n(x-a_i)^2 + (y-b_i)^2 = R^2$

which is incorrect (unless $n=1$).

Comment: Ahh, thank you! When I multiplied out the square root in the denominator (post differentiation), it doesn't just cancel against the zero on the RHS since there are multiple terms on the LHS.